# How to pass data from servlet to jsp code (out side the form)?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have written jsp code to draw a chart by taking data from the servlet .
I have kept "submit" button out side the form and correct graph is not drawn .
But when I call a button inside the form instead of chart I'm getting data table with correct data .So I think servlet Data has passed to the form not out side of the form.

**here is my jsp code**

```
 <form  action="NewServlet1" method="Post" >
<center>
        <input type="text" name="website" list="website" placeholder="Enter your website">
        <datalist id="website">
        <option value="https://www.google.lk/">GOOGLE</option>
        <option value="https://www.yahoo.com/">YAHOO</option>
        <option value="https://www.hackerrank.com/">HACKER RANK</option>

        </datalist><br>
        <button id="button2"  name="button2" onclick="submit()" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
         <br><br><br>


    </center></form>

     <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="10000" height="10000" ></canvas>
    </div>
<center> <div>
       <button id="button1"  name="button1" onclick="submit()" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
    </div></center>
    <script>
        function Test(today, time) {
            var ctx = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart")

            , {

                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: today,
                    datasets: [{
                            data: time,
                            label: "Web Service 1",
                            borderColor: "red",
                            fill: false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options:
                        {
                            scales: {xAxes: [{display: true, scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'date and time'}}], yAxes: [{display: true, ticks: {beginAtZero: true, steps: 100, stepValue: 50, max: 6000}}]},

                            hover: {intersect: false },
                            title: {display: true, text: 'response time of selected website'},
                              tooltips: { mode: 'nearest'}

                        }
            });
}
function submit()
{

    $.post("NewServlet1",
            {

            },
            function (data)
            {

                Test(data.today, data.time);
            });
}
```

**this is my servlet code**

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
       response.setContentType("text/html"); //1st line
       String website = request.getParameter("website"); //2nd line
        NewClass1 myclass1 = new NewClass1();
        NewClass2 myclass2 = new NewClass2();
        //String website1 = "https://www.google.lk/";    /*when I use this line instead of 1st
                                                         //and 2nd lines
                                                         //I'm getting perfect graph but I want
                                                         // to take user input not fixed input*/

    try {
        myclass2 = myclass1.myclass(website);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewServlet1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    int time[] = NewClass1.time1;
    String today[]=NewClass1.today;
    NewClass3 myclass3 = new NewClass3();
    myclass3.time=time;
    myclass3.today=today;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(myclass3);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(jsonString);


}
```

can someone make my mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not explicitly mention a submit function, rather use the action parameter of the Form. So when you call the submit function from inside the form it calls the form Action NewServlet1 with the input fields.
2. The call you make from outside the form calls the function Submit that you have explicitly defined. So its not a good practice to define a submit method and its best to use the Form Action and input type submit. So just specify a form with the required action, or rename the method.

Comment: can you please make my mistake ?

Comment: I cannot make your mistake because i dont want to make it

Comment: It's ok :) Thank you for above answers.